# Swift 3 button.addTarget not working on all table cells

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have created an app to allow users to store various voice recordings against reviews. When I display this a table and the data is populated with the following code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let row = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).item
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "voiceRecordingCell", for: indexPath) as! VoiceRecordingTableViewCell
    let voiceRecording = self.voiceRecordings[row] as! NSDictionary

    let isoFormatter = DateFormatter()
    isoFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.000Z'"
    let createdAt = isoFormatter.date(from: voiceRecording["created_at"] as! String)
    self.recordingIndexPaths.insert(indexPath, at: row)

    cell.recording = voiceRecording
    cell.date.text = getDateFormatter("dd-MM-y").string(from: createdAt!)
    cell.time.text = getDateFormatter("HH:mm").string(from: createdAt!)
    cell.length.text = voiceRecording["length"] as? String
    cell.location.text = voiceRecording["location"] as? String

    let audioPlayerController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AudioPlayerController") as! AudioPlayerController

    audioPlayerController.voiceRecording = voiceRecording

    cell.audioPlayer.addSubview(audioPlayerController.view)
    self.addChildViewController(audioPlayerController)
    audioPlayerController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    cell.deleteRecordingButton.tag = row
    cell.deleteRecordingButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteRecordingPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

The cells all appear to be rendering correctly however for the cells that are not initially rendered with the page, the ones I have to scroll down to view, when I click on the buttons either on the audio player controls or the `deleteRecordingButton` nothing happens, its as though the `addTarget` is not being set. The code to set the buttons is being called and doesn't create an error, its just not applying to those button.

The buttons that are initially displayed on the screen have the correct actions and all work perfectly so I know that works.

I'm really at a loss as to what is causing this. I did try searching google and stackoverflow but I've not found anything. Any assistance with this would be greatly received.

--------------- UPDATE -----------

I just tried putting some breakpoints in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}
```

That also only works get called on the top 2 cells or the top one if in landscape!

Comment: Something else is wrong, not here. A cell can only be created though this method so the add target must get called on the new cells. Your break point in target handler method is not getting reached?

Comment: For instance I have 3 rows in a table. When I open the page the addTarget method is called 3 times, however only the 2 buttons that are visible work.

Comment: Yes I get your point. So in this situation, when you click on the 3rd button, your `deleteRecordingPressed` function is not triggered at all by setting a break point?

Comment: No at all but if I press the other 2 its works fine. I did notice that when I had the screen in landscape only the top 1 would work and the others would be broken which is why i figured it was something to do with the buttons that were not being shown

Comment: cell.deleteRecordingButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourViewController.deleteRecordingPressed(_:)), for:.touchUpInside) try this

Comment: thanks @BHAVIKPANCHAL but didn't help

Comment: what error gettting ?

Comment: no errors at all, the button just does not work

Comment: click on button then call the function or not? set debug point there?

Comment: I put a breakpoint in the func, its gets called fine for the buttons that are displayed to start with but any that are off the screen lose their actions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148607/discussion-between-bhavik-panchal-and-mic).

Comment: if call the function then after what you want ?

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since the cell gets reused all the time the reference get lost. 
Try something like this:

```
class ButtonTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    typealias TapClosure = () -> Void

    var buttonTapped: TapClosure?

    @IBAction func buttonTouchUpInside(sender: UIButton) {
        buttonTapped?()
    }

}

extension TestViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "identifier", for: indexPath) as! ButtonTableViewCell

        cell.buttonTapped = {
            print("Button tapped")
        }

        return cell
    }

}
```

And another tipp. Never init an `DateFormatter` in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Instead create it in viewDidLoad or in a static struct for reuse.

Comment: The cell get reused and then the target reference is added again. Look **carefully** in `cellForRowAt`

Comment: Ah that makes sense and would cause the issue I was having, I will just test this and let you know if it works. thanks :)

Comment: @SWIE I can confirm this doesn't work, thanks for you effort though

Comment: ps I did move my data formatter instance into the viewDidLoad method as you explained, that does make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have figured this out...

This was happening because I was using a scrollview with to scroll up and down the table without using the tables native scroll functionality.

When using the tables scroll functionality the buttons are applied the actions as they are brought into the view. This is handled by the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {` method. However when you do it the way I was it initially renders all the cells and the ones that are off the screen don't work!

Its a little bit annoying working in this way but at least I now know about it.